# Change the default icon allignment of windows desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons, desktop-customization

### Scenario

When a file is created or moved inside the desktop dir, the default alignment is from **left-top to down**:

[image]

---

### Problem

What I would like to do is to assign a different default alignment, for example from left-bottom to right:

[image]

---

### Question

Is this possible?

Is there any reg-key that allows you to do this? or any dll resource to edit?

---

### Research

I can imagine that the cultures who write from right to left or for example the Chinese version of Windows maybe have a different default alignment (from right-top to down or from right-top to left...) so I don't think this is a crazy idea.

PS: Notice that I don't want to use programs to change the POSITION of my desktop icons, for example the typical program that draws a "clock" or figures with the icons... that is sh*t, I want to change the default alignment in Windows for new created/moved files into the desktop dir.

PS2: I'm using Windows 7.